# Outlook 2016: Your mailbox has been temporarily moved on Microsoft Exchange server” message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

Getting the following Outlook issue this morning.
Clicked to open Outlook this morning and got the following Error:

[image]

I have followed the steps on the [Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3197025/-your-mailbox-has-been-temporarily-moved-to-microsoft-exchange-server) removed the old profiles, but the issue still persist.

I have also tried to remove old .ost files from **C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook** and then removed the old profile and recreated a new one - still the issue persists.

Running out of ideas. Help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your profile is corrupted. I think you did go to the right support page. I followed the same steps with two caveats:

A. I exited Skype for Business, which seems to hold the *.ost files hostage until you do

B. I removed *every profile*, unlike the suggestion in the support page that says not to remove the primary profile.

These are the steps I followed:

1. Exit Outlook *and* Skype for Business and backup your old data files in **C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook** in case there might be reason to return and make the effort to try to salvage anything.
2. In Control Panel, click or double-click Mail.
3. Click Show Profiles.
4. In the Mail dialog box, select the profile that you want to remove, and then click Remove.
5. The following warning message is displayed:
   Careful, if you remove this profile, offline cached contents for its accounts will be deleted. Learn how to make a backup of the offline .ost files for the accounts. Do you want to continue?
6. Click Yes to continue.
7. Repeat step 4 and step 5 for all other Outlook profiles.
8. Start Outlook.

The above is borrowed from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3197025/your-mailbox-has-been-temporarily-moved-to-microsoft-exchange-server-m, which suggests that you don't delete the user's primary profile. However, I deleted it too and went and recreated it because it seemed to be the one at fault in the first place. Setup from scratch after step 8 above was merely a two-step process where I simply,

1. Named my new profile as "Outlook" and clicked OK.
2. Inserted my e-mail address and then just clicked Connect.

Problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

New an Outlook profile with your Exchange account for testing.

As an Exchange administrator, check the status of mailbox migration in Exchange server, complete the move request and check it again.
If you are not an Exchange admin, contact your admin to check it.